# Using Rails and HAML to output objects in pairs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

Iterating over 'posts' I want to create a row div which will contain two post divs:

```
<div id="row">
  <div id="post"> ... </div>
  <div id="post"> ... </div>
</div>
<div id="row">
  <div id="post"> ... </div>
  <div id="post"> ... </div>
</div>
```

If I try this:

```
- @posts.each_with_index do |post,index|
  - if index %2 == 0
    .row
      .post
  - else
    .post
```

...then I get:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="post"></div>
</div>
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="post"></div>
</div>
<div class="post"></div>
```

I can see why this happens but I can't figure out how to do it correctly. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
When accessing object attributes as per apneadiving's suggesion, I receive errors when the last slice contains only a single post. For example, the following...

```
- @posts.each_slice(2) do |post1, post2|
    .row
      .post= post1.title
      .post= post2.title
```

returns the error "undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass" when there are an odd number of posts. To get around this I have used this:

```
- @posts.each_slice(2) do |post1, post2|
    .row
      .post= post1.title
      .post= post2.title unless post2.nil?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd take my posts 2 by 2, I can't see how to do otherwise with haml:

```
- @posts.each_slice(2) do |post1, post2|
    .row
      .post= post1
      .post= post2
```

Comment: I really like that. A very neat solution.

Comment: Thanks - this works well for me. I'm relatively new to Ruby and this is my first encounter with each_slice. Very handy!

Answer (score 0):

For tasks like this i prefer to use erb templates, that adds more flexibility, use it and you will see that your problem will solve so easy. Structuring of haml imposes some restrictions on the tasks implementation.

```
<% @posts.each_with_index do |post, index| %>
  <% if index %2 == 0 %>
    <div class="row">
  <% end %>
  <div class="post></div>
  <% if index %2 != 0 %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: do you really consider it helps in any way?

Comment: @Master-K thanks for the response. I was beginning to think that a move to erb might be needed. However apneadiving's solution works well.